# How to overriding css by using dom element in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I want to override my inline css by using dom and when I am going for !important , color doesn't work.

```
 componentDidMount(){
    document.getElementById("para").style.color = "red !important"
  }
```

Here is the default example , why it doesn't work ?

I am also giving link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-draft-wysiwyg-editor-ppctk

Comment: Don't use `document.getElement...` and react together, you're doing react wrong. If you want to set `styles` based on things happening, those `styles` should be a part of `state`. EDIT: [this is the quickest thing I can google that will shows you how to do it reasonably well](https://malcoded.com/posts/react-component-style/)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether using React syntax or not, attribute `!important` value has to be set with a method and cannot be assigned directly. Here are a few examples:

```js
// Specific old IE
if (document.all) {
  element.style.setAttribute('cssText', 'propertyName: value !important');

  // Modern browser
} else {
  element.setAttribute('style', 'propertyName: value !important');
}
```

**or** (probably currently the preferred method)

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

`element.style.setProperty(propertyName, value, priority);` where (optional) `priority` simply requires "important" to be passed.